# Can a function which depends on user input for 2 parameters be initialised with only 1? If so, why?

Tags: c++

```
int main(int arg_count, char*args[])
{
if(arg_count > 1){
    name = string(args[1]);
    print_menu(name);

}
else {
    cout << "Username not supplied, exiting the program"<< endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

While executing the function int main, I understand that the function expects some parameters for it to run. What do the parameters *int arg_count* and *char*args[]* mean?

Comment: *What do the parameters int arg_count and charargs[]* mean?*: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Conventionally, they are `(int argc, char* argv[])` or `(int argc, char** argv)`.  I like to repackage the parameters, not including `argv[0]`, into `auto args = vector<string>(argv+1, argv+argc);` since `string` objects are much easier to work with.

Comment: @Elijay could also use `string_view`, which would also help with accidentally modifying command line arguments.

Comment: Damn, closed, I had an answer ready to go... I suspect the OP is getting confused by `arg_count` and `args` - these refer to *the arguments passed to the program on launch by the operating system*, and have nothing to do with the function parameters in terms of code. If a C++ function expects two parameters, it must be given two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function takes the command-line arguments supplied when running the program. `arg_count` is the number of such arguments passed, and `args` is an array of those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

On any OS, when you execute your program, there are ways to pass command line arguments..in order to support that, the entry point function of your C++ program takes in these 2 arguments. The first is the number of arguments, and second is the array of argument strings that "might" have been passed. Note that, it can be empty , so your code must check the `argc`/arg count, so that you don't access outside the bounds. Refer [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)